# Pandas: New column multipling by values of correlation

Tags: python, pandas, correlation

This is my dataframe (fictitious data):

```
     Name    Passes     Shots    Goals    Duels    Assists    Dribbles
1   Player 1     20        5       3      20       2            15
2   Player 2     30        6       2      15       1            3
3   Player 3     10        3       3      16       0            2
4   Player 4     15        9       0      22       3            14
5   Player 5     18        8       1      19       2            11
6   Player 6     25        7       2      14       5            9
7   Player 7     22        6       0      20       8            13
8   Player 8     20        10      4      16       2            12
9   Player 9     13        4       0      15       1            10
```

I've obtained the results of the correlation between one specific column with the rest of the columns of my dataframe with next code:

```
corr = df.corr()
corr['Goals'].sort_values(ascending=False)
```

Then, the result of corr['Goals'] would be something like (the results are invented, it's just for the idea):

```
Goals       1.0000
Dribbles    0.8001
Passes      0.7881
Shots       0.6000
Duels      -0.5500
Assists    -0.6843
```

I would like to create a new column in the dataframe with the result of multipliying each value of the columns by the number of the correlation. I could do it with the next code but I would like to have something with less code:

```
df['New column'] = df['Goals'] * 1.000 + df['Dribbles'] * 0.8001 + df['Passes'] * 0.7881 + df['Shots'] * 0.6000 + df['Duels'] * -0.5500 + df['Assists'] * -0.6843
```

Any idea how to solve this question? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

With matrix multiplication:

```
df["new"] = df.set_index("Name").dot(corr.Goals).to_numpy()
```

where we set `Name` as the index to keep it aside from the calculations and use `to_numpy` to assign a new column with the values directly,

to get

```
>>> df

       Name  Passes  Shots  Goals  Duels  Assists  Dribbles        new
1  Player 1      20      5      3     20        2        15  -6.300948
2  Player 2      30      6      2     15        1         3  -0.549972
3  Player 3      10      3      3     16        0         2  -2.023544
4  Player 4      15      9      0     22        3        14 -10.656906
5  Player 5      18      8      1     19        2        11  -7.005868
6  Player 6      25      7      2     14        5         9  -3.977859
7  Player 7      22      6      0     20        8        13 -10.919734
8  Player 8      20     10      4     16        2        12  -2.789039
9  Player 9      13      4      0     15        1        10  -6.696956
```

Comment: I thought this solution could resolve the problem, but I receive this error: `ValueError: matrices are not aligned`

Comment: @nokvk If you do this operation again without calculating the `corr` again, you'd receive that error, is that the case? Because this operation adds a new column to the frame so unalignment happens. Can you say look at `print(df.columns)` and see its length? If `"new"` column is there already, operation will err as mentioned.